# I'm not getting the right output?

Tags: java, class, output

I don't know why this is not working, what am I writing wrong?

```
public class Testmain {
   /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Wat n1=new This("john","man");

        System.out.println(((This)n1).toString());

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this as an output :

```
 This@68e26d2e
```

What I should get as an output is this :

```
  John man
```

And yes I know the class names are random. So I wrote toString() method in the class "This", but it's still not working. I have a field `firstname` in the superclass and field `gender` in the subclass, but now in the output I'm not getting the `gender`, only `firstname`.

Comment: You have to override toString method in your class and return desired output

Comment: The default toString of class Object, displays its class and its hashcode. If this is not what interests you, you have to overide toString to fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You must override method

```
@Override
public String toString() { 
     return "Name: " + name + " \n Gender:" + gender; 
}
```

name, gender it's you private members which you set in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

override the `toString()` method  in  `This`

ex:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "whatever you want";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`This@68e26d2e` is just the hexadecimal representation of the memory address of your `This` class. Every object will have this by default. To have your own String representation, you must `override` the `toString()` method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return < your String here >;
}
```